# Is there a way to turn off case sensitivity when using unique in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to get rid of non-unique lines in a dataframe in R using the unique function, but do not want to count lines that differ only in capitalization in one of the character vector values as unique. Is there a way to turn off case sensitivity when using the unique function?

Comment: `unique(tolower(x))`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `unique(tolower(your_var))`